# Python create a Popen shell command list

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, popen

Please can someone help me create a Popen command line list from this...

```
identify  -format %b:%w:%h:%r:%# myimage.jpg
```

I have this:

```
cmd=Popen(['identify -format', '%b:%w:%h:%r:%#', 'myimage.jpg'])
```

But that does not work. the  original command line works fine in the command line. But just cannot get it working in python this way.

Comment: explain your problem in a mannered fashion. Its hard for us to know what the problem is. show us some code and add few examples, also full error message

Comment: Its like I said I want to execute this command line argument for use in python using Popen.  identify -format %b:%w:%h:%r:%# myimage.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
cmd=Popen(['identify', '-format', '%b:%w:%h:%r:%#', 'myimage.jpg'])
```

you have to break down args as a list of *separate* arguments